# How is melatonin production related to proteins produced by clock genes?

Tags: genetics, endocrinology, melatonin

I am a high school student learning about feedback mechanisms. My teacher gave an example of how proteins produced by clock genes are related to melatonin production. However, I'm confused about the relationship between constant darkness, clock gene protein production, and melatonin production. My teacher said that constant darkness results in a drop in proteins produced by clock genes, but wouldn't melatonin production increase in constant darkness? Does this mean that the relationship between clock gene protein production and melatonin production is inverse? I would appreciate clarification on this topic.

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, in the absence of a real answer though, I'd suggest looking at a review paper on the topic: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0928425711000040?casa_token=VRcXQ1EiXEMAAAAA:1oQJp3oNyRn9cEIZqEhbU4RWHUoWDQDi3HSdYK5xsVixDhigc4gKMk_G8xmQdkf-jIE3WAHydus.